# Authorize Cloud SQL Admin API call from Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to build small function (which later deployed to cloud function) to restore BAK file to cloud sql. This function will be trigerred by cron.
I'm kind of lost when reading the docs about authorize this API: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/import-export/importing#importing_data_from_a_bak_file_in

Already create service account which include this role: Cloud SQL Admin, Storage Admin, Storage Object Admin, Storage Object Viewer and choose that Service Account from dropdown when creating Cloud Function but not work.

Also tried generating API keys after reading this: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/admin-api/how-tos/authorizing

So my POST url became this:

`https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/project-id/instances/instance-id/import?key=generatedAPIKey`

but still got an error:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Do I need to use Oauth 2 for this? This is my code in Cloud Function:

```
import http.client
import mimetypes

def restore_bak(request):
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.googleapis.com")
    payload = "{\r\n \"importContext\":\r\n   {\r\n      \"fileType\": \"BAK\",\r\n      \"uri\": \"gs://{bucket_name}/{backup_name}.bak\",\r\n      \"database\": \"{database_name}\"\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n"
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    conn.request("POST", "/sql/v1beta4/projects/{project_id}/instances/{instance_name}/import", payload, headers)
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))
    return(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like python, so I would recommend using the [Discovery Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client). This library provides a convient wrapper around the SQL Admin API:

```py
# Construct the service object for the interacting with the Cloud SQL Admin API.
service = discovery.build('sqladmin', 'v1beta4', http=http)

req = service.instances().list(project="PROJECT_ID")
resp = req.execute()
print json.dumps(resp, indent=2)
```

By default, this library uses the "[Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)" strategy to obtain your credentials from the environment.

You can also manually authenticate your requests (for example, if you want to use asyncio) by creating an oauth2 token and setting it as a header in your request. The easiest way to do this is to use the google-auth package to get the ADC and set it as a header:

```py
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(credentials.token),
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
```

Comment: I've tried manually authenticate my request using google-auth package and listed google-auth==1.20.1 on requirements.txt but still no luck and got the same error.
Is there something I miss?

Comment: If you've set the "Authorization" header, you should be getting a different error (or a success). I would check that you're code in setting the headers correctly, or use the Python discovery client which handles all of this for you.

Comment: Sorry if asking too much, I'm relatively new, do I need to change project/project_id before google.auth.default()?

Here's how I setting the header I copied from you:

```credentials, project = google.auth.default()
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(credentials.token),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
print (headers)
```
When I run on local with gcloud sdk installed it return the bearer None, maybe this is why I still unauthenticated:

```{'Authorization': 'Bearer None', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}```

Same output when deployed to cloud function

Comment: @Chairul, in serveless services as App Engine and Cloud function it is not possible to get access or install Gcloud SDK, the best way to use SQL admin API on cloud functions is by using  [Discovery client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)
This method will use the service account associated to you function

Comment: @Chairul - I've updated my example to include a missing step required to refresh the token. You can find more instructions on how the library works here: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#obtaining-credentials